# Upload txt file on AWS S3 using ESP32

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, arduino-esp32

I got stuck at one point, how to upload the txt file in S3 using ESP32 arduino framework.

I know how to do it using boto3 but not with the Arduino.

Any help would be appreciable!

Comment: What do you mean by "I know how to do it using boto3 but not with the Arduino."? Can you run a Python program on the Arduino that uses boto3? Does it have Internet access?

Answer (score 1):

What I mean to say is, I can upload the file to AWS S3 in python using boto 3 but I need to implement the same thing in Arduino. Is there any way I can do in Arduino ? Where I can directly upload my file to desired bucket.

There is no communication between Arduino and python like using serial communication or WiFi.

Comment: Don't mark this as an answer. Reply to the comment as a comment